# split divs by 3 after getjson function success and appending to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

This is an attempt for list of twitch.tv streamers, part of a FreeCodeCamp project. After the document.ready function appends the data to divs(bs4 cards), it needs to be stacked in card-decks in the order of 3.
I'm trying a splitByThree function but it doesnt seem to work.
How to do this using promises? Any help is much appreciated.

```js
let streamers = ["ESL_SC2",
        "ESL_CSGO", "freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "notmichaelmcdonald", "RobotCaleb", "medrybw", "thomasballinger", "joe_at_underflow", "noobs2ninjas", "mdwasp", "beohoff", "xenocomagain"
    ];
    
    let getDATA = function(arr) {
        let cb = '?client_id=c292fn290f4pac7cpk4j4t137uk3tn&callback=?';
        let url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';

        arr.forEach(function(stream) {

            let newUrl = url + 'streams/' + stream + cb;


            $.getJSON(newUrl).success(function(data) {
                let obj = {};
                let streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
                if (streaming) {
                    obj.theme = 'card-success';
                    obj.username = stream;
                } else {
                    obj.theme = 'card-danger';
                    obj.username = stream;
                }
                
                $.getJSON(url + 'users/' + stream + cb).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    obj.logo = data.logo;
                    $(".streamers").append('<div class="streamer card col-4 ' + obj.theme + '"><img class="rounded w-25" src=' + obj.logo + '>' + obj.username + '</div>');
                });
            });            
        });
    };

    function splitByThree() {
        var divs = $(".streamers > .streamer");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
            divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='card-deck'></div>");
        }
    }

    let readyFN  = function () {
        getDATA(streamers).then(function(){return splitByThree()});
        
    };
    $(document).ready(readyFN);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="streamers"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute:

```
getDATA(streamers).then(function(){return splitByThree()});
```

the function getDATA must return an array of ***[deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)*** objects. ***[When](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)*** this array has ***[done](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)*** you can execute splitByThree function.

If you want to use the [deferred then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) in order to handle done and fail you can reject instead to resolve the deferred elements when a fail happens.

In this way your line of code becomes:

```
$.when.apply($, getDATA(streamers)).done(function () {
    splitByThree()
});
```

The snippet:

```js
let streamers = ["ESL_SC2",
                 "ESL_CSGO", "freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "notmichaelmcdonald", "RobotCaleb", "medrybw",
                 "thomasballinger", "joe_at_underflow", "noobs2ninjas", "mdwasp", "beohoff", "xenocomagain"
                ];


let getDATA = function (arr) {
  //
  // create and initialize the deferred array to return
  //
  var deferredArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function (ele, idx) {
    deferredArr.push($.Deferred());
  });


  let cb = '?client_id=c292fn290f4pac7cpk4j4t137uk3tn&callback=?';
  let url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';

  arr.forEach(function (stream, idx) {
    let newUrl = url + 'streams/' + stream + cb;
    $.getJSON(newUrl).success(function (data) {
      let obj = {};
      let streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
      if (streaming) {
        obj.theme = 'card-success';
        obj.username = stream;
      } else {
        obj.theme = 'card-danger';
        obj.username = stream;
      }

      $.getJSON(url + 'users/' + stream + cb).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        obj.logo = data.logo;
        $(".streamers").append('<div class="streamer card col-4 ' + obj.theme + '"><img class="rounded w-25" src=' + obj.logo + '>' + obj.username + '</div>');
        //
        // resolve the current deferred element
        //
        deferredArr[idx].resolve();
      }).fail(function () {
        //
        // resolve (reject using then instead of done)
        // the current deferred element
        //
        deferredArr[idx].resolve();
      });
    }).fail(function () {
      //
      // resolve (reject using then instead of done)
      // the current deferred element
      //
      deferredArr[idx].resolve();
    });
  });
  return deferredArr;
};

function splitByThree() {
  console.log('splitByThree runs....');
  var divs = $(".streamers > .streamer");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
    divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='card-deck'></div>");
  }
}

let readyFN = function () {
  $.when.apply($, getDATA(streamers)).done(function () {
    splitByThree()
  });
};
$(document).ready(readyFN);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="streamers"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `splitByThree` function to inside the `getDATA` function. Once the JSON data is fetched only then the `splitByThree` function should be called, otherwise due to Asynchronous nature of execution the `splitByThree` function wouldn't work correctly as the data on which the `splitByThree` function operates is not valid.

```
let streamers = ["ESL_SC2",
        "ESL_CSGO", "freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "notmichaelmcdonald", "RobotCaleb", "medrybw", "thomasballinger", "joe_at_underflow", "noobs2ninjas", "mdwasp", "beohoff", "xenocomagain"
    ];

        let streamers = ["ESL_SC2",
        "ESL_CSGO", "freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "notmichaelmcdonald", "RobotCaleb", "medrybw", "thomasballinger", "joe_at_underflow", "noobs2ninjas", "mdwasp", "beohoff", "xenocomagain"
    ];

    let getDATA = function(arr) {
        let cb = '?client_id=c292fn290f4pac7cpk4j4t137uk3tn&callback=?';
        let url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';

        arr.forEach(function(stream) {

            let newUrl = url + 'streams/' + stream + cb;


            $.getJSON(newUrl).success(function(data) {
                let obj = {};
                let streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
                if (streaming) {
                    obj.theme = 'card-success';
                    obj.username = stream;
                } else {
                    obj.theme = 'card-danger';
                    obj.username = stream;
                }

                $.getJSON(url + 'users/' + stream + cb).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    obj.logo = data.logo;
                    $(".streamers").append('<div class="streamer card col-4 ' + obj.theme + '"><img class="rounded w-25" src=' + obj.logo + '>' + obj.username + '</div>');
                    splitByThree();
                });
            });            
        });

    };

    function splitByThree() {
        var divs = $(".streamers > .streamer");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
            divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='card-deck'></div>");
        }
    }

    let readyFN  = function () {
        getDATA(streamers);

    };
    $(document).ready(readyFN);
```